# Can't set maxJsonLength

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm getting this error:

> Internal Server Error: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

I have googled answers for this and have found 2 answers, neither of which seem to be working for me.  I have tried to add the maxJsonLength setting to the web.config but it's being ignored.  As well, I have tried in the C# code to set MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue; but I am using MVC 2.0 and it appears this only works in MVC 4?  Can anyone help me set the maxJsonLength property properly?  Here is where I'm getting the error.

```
 public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var jsonResult = new JsonResult
                             {
                              Data = result.ViewData.Model, 
                              JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                             };


        filterContext.Result = jsonResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure it works or not but i found some solution , please try below

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

or

```
public ActionResult SomeControllerAction()
{
  var jsonResult = Json(veryLargeCollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
  return jsonResult;
}
```

Comment: I tried both of these options.  The Web.config option is ignored, and unless I'm doing something wrong, it appears MVC2 doesn't have the MaxJsonLength property available.

Comment: The second one fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

Got it, using the following code

```
 public ActionResult MyFancyMethod()
 {
     var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };
     var result = new ContentResult
     {
         Content = serializer.Serialize(myBigData),
         ContentType = "application/json"
     };
     return result;
}
```